# iOS Parse Inner Json

Tags: ios, json, nsarray

Hi I have the following json that i need to parse, however, I'm struggling to parse the inner array. What I have currently just prints each of the inner arrays but I'd like to print say each title and add the titles to an array. Thank you for any help!

**JSON**

```
{"nodes":[{
    "node":{
        "nid":"1420857",
        "title":"Title 1",
        "votes":"182",
        "popular":"True",
        "teaser":"Teaser 1"
    }},
    {"node":{
        "nid":"1186152",
        "title":"Title 2",
        "votes":"140",
        "popular":"True",
        "teaser":"Teaser 2"
    }},
    {"node":{
        "nid":"299856",
        "title":"Title 3",
        "votes":"136",
        "popular":"True",
        "teaser":"Teaser 3"
    }}
]}
```

**Json Parser**

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.somefilename.json"]];
    if (jsonData) {
        id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error is %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }
        NSArray *keys = [jsonObjects allKeys];
        for (NSString *key in keys) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [jsonObjects objectForKey:key]);
        }
    } else {
        // Handle Error
    }
```

Comment: it works all right, does exactly what is supposed to do. what's the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by inner array?  There is only one array in what you posted, everything else is a dictionary. What exactly is it that you want to parse?

Comment: Like I need to print say each title in my loop I've tried a lot of things but can't figure how to grab those objects inside what i'm printing. Just edited my question sorry that I wasn't clear but I'd pretty much just like to print each title in my loop rather than each array

Comment: You HAVE already grabbed them

Comment: It is NSDictionary --> NSArray --> NSDictionary --> NSDictionary --> NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just typecast it:

```
NSArray *nodes = (NSArray*)[jsonObjects objectForKey:@"nodes"];
for (NSDictionary *node in nodes){
     // do stuff...
}
```

Methods that return `id` (like `-[objectForKey:]`, and `-[objectAtIndex:]`) can return any objective-c object. You'll need to know ahead of time what to typecast it into to perform the appropriate operations on it. JSON is converted to the NSObject equivalents:

- `object` -> `NSDictionary`
- `array` -> `NSArray`
- `string` -> `NSString`
- `number` -> `NSNumber`
- `boolean` -> `NSNumber`
- `float` -> `NSNumber`
- `null` -> `NSNull`

To differentiate between the various NSNumbers, you'll have to call the appropriate type method: `-[intValue]`, `-[boolValue]`, `-[floatValue]`. Check out the [NSNumber docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

Comment: In the do stuff comment how could i just log the title

Comment: I tried NSLog(@"%@",[node objectForKey:@"title"]); however that just gives me null

Comment: It's a nested object, so you'll need to do [(NSDictionary *)[node objectForKey:@"node"] objectForKey:@"title"];

Comment: Ahh perfect thanks a ton for the help sorry I'm so new to this :)

Comment: For numbers take a look at `[NSNumberFormatter numberFromString:]` it makes your life easy if you're not certain of the format of the numbers, it just parses the string to a number value, you can decide later how you want to use it: `int, float`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my method for json parsing,

**Parse Method:**

```
    -(void)jsonDeserialize:(NSString *)key fromDict:(id)content completionHandler:(void (^) (id parsedData, NSDictionary *fromDict))completionHandler{
    if (key==nil && content ==nil) {
        completionHandler(nil,nil);
    }
    if ([content isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        for (NSDictionary *obj in content) {
          [self jsonDeserialize:key fromDict:obj completionHandler:completionHandler];
        }
    }
    if ([content isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        id result = [content objectForKey:key];
        if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || result == nil) {
            NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)content;
            NSArray *keys = [temp allKeys];
            for (NSString *ikey in keys) {
             [self jsonDeserialize:key fromDict:[content objectForKey:ikey] completionHandler:completionHandler];
            }
        }else{
            completionHandler(result,content);
        }
    }
}
```

**Method Call:**

```
 NSData *content = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Sample" ofType:@"json"]];
    NSError *error;
```

> //to get serialized json data...

```
   id dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:content options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

> //get data for key called *GetInfo*

```
     [self jsonDeserialize:@"GetInfo" fromDict:dictionary completionHandler:^(id parsedData, NSDictionary *fromDict) {
            NSLog(@"%@ - %@",parsedData,fromDict);
        }];
```